# How can I take the average of all values in the second dimention of an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm using this code along with a method that generates random numbers to fill my arrays with the student IDs and quiz scores. Next I would like to find the average/min/max of all the quiz scores. I'm really stuck. Any and all help is appreciated.

```
private class FillButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int quizScore, firstIDin = firstID, row, column;
        int[] studentIDsin = new int[numberStudents];
        int[][] quizin = new int[numberStudents][numberQuizes];

        for(row=0; row<numberStudents; row++) {
            studentIDsin[row] = firstIDin;
            firstIDin+=1;
        }
        for(row=0; row<numberStudents; row++) {
            studentIDs[row] = studentIDsin[row];
        }
        for(row=0; row<numberStudents; row++) {
            for(column=0; column<numberQuizes;column++) {
                quizScore = (int) rand();
                quizin[row][column]= quizScore;
            }
        }
        for(row=0; row<numberStudents; row++) {
            for(column=0; column<numberQuizes;column++)
                quiz[row][column]= quizin[row][column];
        }
        dispResultsMenuPriv.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

}

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your attempting here. Is this just a test scenario? Or would you like this to work in a "real" quiz...i.e..once a student submits a score, calculate their new average, min and max?

Comment: It is just a test scenario.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(row=0; row<numberStudents; row++) {
    int min = 0, max = 0;
    float average = 0.0f;
    for(column=0; column<numberQuizes;column++) {
        average += quizin[row][column];
        min = (quizin[row][column] < min) ? quizin[row][column] : min;
        max = (quizin[row][column] > max) ? quizin[row][column] : max;
    }
    average = average/numberQuizzes;
}
```

Using this code, you can easily find the min, max and average of all quiz scores for each student.

Comment: What if I wanted to find the average/min/max of all the students quizzes?

Comment: Then define the min, max outside the first for loop. Also, define a new variable sumOfAverages as float outside the first for loop. Then for each student, as their average is being calculated, add that average to the sumOfAverage. Finally, divide the somOfAverage by numberStudents to get the average for all the students, outside the main for loop.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    double[] avg = new double[numberQuizes];
    int[] min = new int[numberQuizes];
    int[] max = new int[numberQuizes];

    // for each student
    for (int[] a : quizin) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberQuizes; i++) {
            int score = a[i];
            avg[i] += score;
            if (min[i] > score) {
                min[i] = score;
            }
            if (max[i] < score) {
                max[i] = score;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numberQuizes; i++) {
        avg[i] /= numberStudents;
    }
```